# round clickable profile image with a button on the bottom in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image][image]I want to make a round clickable profile image which will a have button on the bottom . i can do that for a normal image but when it comes to rounded image, the button is taking the size of the container in which this image and button are available .
thanks

```css
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-thumbnail img-circle">
  <div style="position: relative; padding: 0; cursor: pointer;" type="file">
    <img class="img-circle" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;" >
    <span style="position: absolute; color: red; bottom: 20px; left: 40px;">UPLOAD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share an example of your code . see here how to ask a question so you can get help from us : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MihaiT i hope this works !
i added a little code, hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: well not really. first of all the img has the same class as the container ( `.img-circle` )  why is that ?

Comment: @MihaiT that container was suppose to have a radius of 50% which is a thumbnail.

Comment: see my answer below. let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok. see here. i think i understood what you wanted to achieve .
let me know if it helps

NOTE : the `img.img-circle {background:black; }` is just for example purpose so you can see where the img should be. in your code you don't have to include this

```css
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
img.img-circle {
  background:black;
}
span {
 left:0;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 bottom:0;
 padding:20px 0;
}
.img-thumbnail {
border-radius: 0;
display:inline-block;
background:#dbdbdb;
padding:20px;
 }
.img-thumbnail > div {
display:inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
height: 140px;
border: 5px solid #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px #333;
box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px #333;
border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-thumbnail img-circle">
  <div style="position: relative; padding: 0; cursor: pointer;" type="file">
    <img class="img-circle" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;" >
    <span style="position: absolute; color: red; ">UPLOAD</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img-thumbnail img-circle">
  <div style=" position: relative;padding: 0; cursor: pointer;" type="file">
    <img class="img-circle" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;" >
    <span style="position: absolute; color: red; ">UPLOAD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: didnt work , i have uploaded an image , can u please check it once and help me to make one like that

Comment: the button down there has width of the div which is not rounded and is overflowing from the img and taking the width of the first div

Comment: edited my answer again. the result it's exactly as your picture. removed the css from `.img-thumbnail` and added it to the relative div inside.
if it still doesn't work for you. please share your code that it's not working or at worse, a screenshot to see what's wrong

Comment: its not just the span tag , there should be that background . and when i give that background , it takes the width of its parent div which is not rounded and comes with no border-radius!

Comment: well. upload a screenshot please. because i don't understand why in the answer i gave you it works. and in your code it doesn't

Comment: i uploaded the result i'm getting , so please check it once .

Comment: are you sure you checked my last edit to the code `.img-thumbnail > div ` ? it should work if in the snippet works. something you forgot to add to your code.

Comment: well. why in the snippet is working and in your code it doesn't ? :) give me a link to your working proj so i can inspect it.

Comment: it worked , thank you so much !!
make a mistake in the code .. 
thanks buddy

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one:

```
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.img-circle {
  background:green;
}
span {

 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 background:white;
 bottom:0;

 padding:20px 0;
 opacity:.5
}
.img-thumbnail {
display:inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
height: 140px;
border: 5px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px #dbdbdb;
}
```

[**Here Updated  Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/hhe74bL7/4/)

Comment: @RaminDaqiq wait few minutes sir